# how to run a .net core web application in linux?

Tags: asp.net, linux, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, redhat

I created an application via .net cli

```
dotnet new web
```

created a release folder , changed permission on the folder then publish it to a folder ,

```
sudo mkdir /release/mysite
sudo chown username release/mysite
dotnet publish -c Release -o /release/mysite
```

I created a 'mysite.service' ( code below ) and ran it as a service and everything works.

```
sudo cp mysite.service /etc/systemd/system/mysite.service
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start mysite
sudo systemctl status mysite
```

i can issue a curl http://localhost:5000 and get a default hello world message , also i could go to the browser and load the page with the same message.

now when i create a new mvc app with command - > dotnet new mvc , and do all of the steps as before, then start the service , then checkout status , i get an error -

```
 process:  2938748 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dotnet /release/mvcApp (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
Main PID:  2938748 (code=exited, status=200/CHDIR)
   Tasks: 0 (limit: 20..)
   Memory 0B
   CGroup: /system.slice/mvcApp.service
```

Question: I'm not sure why it fails for the mvc app, all the steps are identical to earlier project but i'm not sure why it fails to start this project.

file : mysite.service

```
[Unit]
Description=ASP.NET Core web template

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/release/mysite
ExecStart=release/mysite/mysite
SyslogIdentifier=mysite

User=myusername

Restart=always
RestartSec=5
KillSignal=SIGINT
Environment=ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
Environment=DOTNET_PRINT_TELEMETRY_MESSAGE=false
Environment=DOTNET_ROOT=/opt/rh/rh-dotnet31/root/usr/lib64/dotnet

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Comment: may I ask you an install is Apache or Nginx

Comment: To host ASP.NET Core on Linux, you need to configure a reverse proxy server, refer these articles: [Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Nginx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-nginx?view=aspnetcore-6.0) and [Host ASP.NET Core on Linux with Apache](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/linux-apache?view=aspnetcore-6.0).